# How to have a UIView of a UIViewController that will be presented modally always be present at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

In my project I'll have two view controllers, one with a large UIView subview in the bottom portion (This is the View Controller 1 in my diagram), and when the user taps on this UIView it would move up to show the second view controller's view. This is pretty much like the point of interest view in Google Maps for iOS. When you've searched for a place it shows a small view at the bottom of the screen which then expands to fill the screen when interacted with - this is effectively what I'm looking to do.

So my question is, what would be the best way to go about implementing this? Ultimately it seems to be much like presenting a UIViewController modally, except its UIView is always present, albeit in difference sizes.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't be a modal view, since you would lose interaction on the previous view, plus with anything other than a popover on an iPad, view controllers are full screen. Consider creating a child UIView on the same view controller. Use gesture recognizers to control the actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'd need two separate view controllers. All you need to do is customise a little bit your `UIScrollView` in your `UIViewController`.

First, you need to setContentSize of your scrollView. Then, you need to prevent your `UIScrollView` to scroll, because you don't want it to scroll.

```
  self.scrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.scrollView.delegate = self;
  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 568 + x  ); // x represents the height of white screen in your first view controller.
  self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
  self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Second, you add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIView` that will need to display entirely on the screen. Here is a piece of code you can use

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer =
      [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                              action:@selector(tapped:)];
 tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
 [view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Finally, you can implement `tapped` method to display entirely new `UIView` on the screen by changing `contentOffset` of your `UIScrollView`. Don't forget to disappear  navigation bar. So,

```
- (void)tapped{
  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
  [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,view1.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
}
```

Well, finally, you display entirely your second view on the screen. I used static values assuming that your using iPhone >5, but you can use dynamic values of height depending on device you're running. Don't forget to `setUserInteractionEnabled` in your second view.

My mistake i think you don't want to navigation bar, but not a big deal, just you need to change setContentOffset y value and not use `navigationBarHidden` properties.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll look at trying this out on the weekend, then I'll come and accept this answer.

Comment: @mMo, did you try that ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a single view controller and make the lower view a subview of it.  When you detect a tap in your main view, you can slide the bottom view up and adjust the sizes and locations of both views as needed.